# How to select distinct rows, but repeat if it has a different row between the equal ones

Tags: sql-server, select, distinct

Having data like this:

```
id   text   bit  date
1    row     1   2016-11-24
2    row     1   2016-11-25
3    row     0   2016-11-26
4    row     1   2016-11-27
```

I want to select the data based on where the text and bit columns are distinct, but based on some order, in this case the id, the data changes between two identical rows, it should duplicate this row on the selection.

So, if I use `distinct` on SQL, I would get rows 1 and 3, but I want to retreive rows 1, 3 and 4, because even 1 and 4 being identical, row 3 is between then when ordering by id.

With a larger dataset, like:

```
id   text   bit  date
1    row     1   2016-11-24
2    row     1   2016-11-25
3    row     0   2016-11-26
4    row     1   2016-11-27
5    foo     1   2016-11-28
6    bar     1   2016-11-29
7    row     1   2016-11-30
8    row     0   2016-12-01
9    row     0   2016-12-02
10   row     1   2016-12-03
```

Again, selecting with distinct on text and bit columns, the query would retrieve rows 1,3,5 and 6, but actually I want rows 1,3,4,5,6,7,8 and 10.

Comment: Sorry if the title is a bit confusing, but I could not find a better way to put it.

Comment: Please show a larger data set which shows all edge cases.  I don't follow your logic.

Comment: Added a case with little more data, see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;with tb(id,[text],[bit],[date]) AS (
      SELECT  1,'row',1,'2016-11-24' union
      SELECT  2,'row',1,'2016-11-25' union
      SELECT  3,'row',0,'2016-11-26' union
      SELECT  4,'row',1,'2016-11-27' union
      SELECT  5,'foo',1,'2016-11-28' union
      SELECT  6,'bar',1,'2016-11-29' union
      SELECT  7,'row',1,'2016-11-30' union
      SELECT  8,'row',0,'2016-12-01' union
      SELECT  9,'row',0,'2016-12-02' union
      SELECT  10,'row',1,'2016-12-03')

    select t1.* from tb as t1
    OUTER APPLY (select top 1 [text],[bit] from tb as tt where tt.id<t1.id order by id desc ) as t2
    where t1.[text]!=isnull(t2.[text],'') or t1.[bit]!=isnull(t2.[bit],1-t1.[bit])
```

result set:

```
1   row 1   2016-11-24
3   row 0   2016-11-26
4   row 1   2016-11-27
5   foo 1   2016-11-28
6   bar 1   2016-11-29
7   row 1   2016-11-30
8   row 0   2016-12-01
10  row 1   2016-12-03
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need a row-by-row operator. You need to know if the new row is the same as the previous one or not. If it is, neglect it, if not, keep it. Here is my solution:

```
 declare @text varchar(100)=(select [text] from Mytable where id = 1)
 declare @bit bit = (select [bit] from Mytable where id = 1)
 declare @Newtext varchar(100)
 declare @Newbit bit
 declare @Mytable table(id int, [text] varchar(100), [bit] bit) 
 Insert into  @Mytable select id,text, bit from Mytable where id = 1
 declare @counter int =2

 while @counter<=(select COUNT(*) from MyTable)
 Begin
    select @Newtext=(select [text] from Mytable where id = @counter)
    select @Newbit=(select [bit] from Mytable where id = @counter)

    IF @Newtext!=@text or @Newbit!=@bit
    Begin   
        Insert into @Mytable 
        select * from Mytable where id = @counter
    End
    set @text = @Newtext
    set @bit = @Newbit;
    set @counter = @counter+1
 END
 select * from @Mytable
```